# change joomla url in 4x

Tags: joomla-4.x

In Native url in joomla 4x like

```
https://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_deals&view=schemes&Itemid=1
```

is there a way to change in from `view=schemes` to `view=list` so as to have url like

```
https://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_deals&view=list&Itemid=1
```

is it possible to do tweaks through src/service/router.php
any help on same

Comment: Do you mean change a URL which is on an incoming HTTP request? If so you could write a system plugin which triggered on the event 'onAfterRoute' and change the input params via input->def('view', 'list'). Would that suit what you need, do you think? Or if you're using SEF URLs then you can use a custom router in src/Service/Router.php to set the view parameter. I think we need a bit more info about your setup.